# HTML Column width/spacing issue

Tags: html

I'm trying to help my son with a HTML project. This is to be only HTML, not CSS.   He has to build a table with his school class schedule.  I can't seem to get the columns to line up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<center> Howie </center>
<p><table border="0"
cellpadding=0>
 </tr>  
  <tr>
    <th>Period</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Teacher</th>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><a href="http://home.ecsdcards.com" target="_blank">Band</a> </td>
    <td>Sletten</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td> Intro to IT</td>
    <td>Rogers</td>  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Biology</td>
    <td>Braet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Study Hall</td>
    <td>Mendoza</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>English II</td>
    <td>Johnson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>US History</td>
    <td>Peterson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Advanced Algebra </td>
    <td>Connon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td><a     href="http://www.earlham.k12.ia.us/Schools/High_School/Staff/Janay_Michel/michel.htm"     target="_blank">Spanish II</a> </td>
    <td>Michel</td>
</table></p>
```

Any suggestions? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Al

Comment: are you "allowed" to use style attribute? lined up how (to left/right/center)?

Comment: Let the kid learn HTML, man. On side note, what you actually want to line ? The columns are lined. http://jsfiddle.net/z6W7L/

Comment: you're right :), but I don't think he is a kid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is malformed.  Among other issues:

- There is a stray closing `</tr>` tag just inside `<table>` tag which needs to be removed.
- After the `<td></td>` containing "Rogers" is an extra `</tr>` which needs to be removed.
- You are missing a `</tr>` at the end of the table before the `</table>` tag.
- Your HTML is missing the closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags.

You should use an HTML validator, such as [this one](http://validator.w3.org/).  This will help you discover these types of issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Im sorry... But please look at the code first.
You are beginning with a `</tr>` That means you want to close a `<tr>`

And at the end you dont close the `<tr>`

Second point, why a table inside of a `<p>` ?

I think if you fix those minor faults.. it will be fine.
Succes with helping your son

Answer (score 0):

They seem messed up because default h alignment for **<th>** is center and for **<td>** is left. If you switch th with td you should be fine.

I also agree with the other answers that you have some html issues. I recommend you write html using a specialized editor.

Answer (score 0):

your open and close tags were somewhat messy.
plus I added some html alignment for the head row.
Next time use a text highlighting editor, it makes life a whole lot easier to find the issues:

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMWye/)

```
<p><table border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
    <th align="left">Period</th>
    <th align="left">Class</th>
    <th align="left">Teacher</th>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><a href="http://home.ecsdcards.com" target="_blank">Band</a> </td>
    <td>Sletten</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td> Intro to IT</td>
    <td>Rogers</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Biology</td>
    <td>Braet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Study Hall</td>
    <td>Mendoza</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>English II</td>
    <td>Johnson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>US History</td>
    <td>Peterson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Advanced Algebra </td>
    <td>Connon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td><a href="http://www.earlham.k12.ia.us/Schools/High_School/Staff/Janay_Michel/michel.htm" target="_blank">Spanish II</a> </td>
    <td>Michel</td>
 </tr>
</table></p>
```